# Divide and merge several maps of the source java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream of identifiers. I want to build an entity which fields should be got from repository by identifier. It should be done by separate methods, each one require identifier. It seems should be done something like this:

```
                   ,---.map(id -> repo.getField1ById(id))---\
<id1,id2,id3,...> -+---.map(id -> repo.getField2ById(id))---+- map((f1,f2) -> entity.builder().field1(f1).field2(f2).build())
```

So is it possible in any simple way?

**UPD**

More detailed.
I need to build list of entities. The fields of entities lies in repository and are accessed by identifier. I have a list of those identifiers. So, for each identifier I need to call the repository methods and those results put into the entity to be built. And I should get a stream (or list) of those built entities.
I started with

```
public List<Entity> method(List<String> identifiers) {
    return identifiers.parallelStream().map(i -> repo.getObjectPropsFirstPart(i)).
...
}
```

and obviously see that now in map chain I am loosing stream of identifiers and cannot return to this, so I should have something like stream division.
Well, I see, that it can be done in such a manner:

```
public List<Entity> method(List<String> identifiers) {
    return identifiers.parallelStream().map(i -> 
        entity.builder().field1(repo.getObjectPropsFirstPart(i))
            .field2(repo.getObjectPropSecondPart(i)).build());
}
```

But nevertheless, is there an opportunity to divide the source stream and per-object merging?

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible to determine what you are asking.  Please rephrase your question with more detail and example input data.  Then show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, I'll try, thanks.

Comment: why not just merge the second and third stages so you have `map(id -> entity.builder().field1(repo.getField1ById(id)).field2(repo.getField2ById(id)).build())` or similar?

Comment: @hacatu Yes, thanks, it can be so, I wrote it above in update. I just wanted to do it in a more parallel way using parallelStream. Even those requests for field1 and field2 to be done in parallel. Can it be?

Comment: Yes, but that depends on how `repo` handles parallel requests.  If you have a promise/future based api, you can just have the function you pass to map create futures holding the values for all the fields you want to extract from `repo` and then wait for both futures to be resolved.  However, there probably would not be much benefit to doing so.  The "parallel" in parallelStream refers to the ability to process different elements in the stream in parallel, so generally doing parallel processing on individual elements is not a good idea

Comment: Parallelism by processing multiple elements in separate threads can already saturate all threads on a processor with independent work, whereas procesing a single element with multiple threads tends to have dependent work and thus be less efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
List<Person> people = List.of(1, 2, 3).parallelStream()
        .flatMap(id -> List.of(PersonProvider.of(id, Merging::ageProvider), PersonProvider.of(id, Merging::nameProvider)).parallelStream())
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId), Merging::mergePerson));
System.out.println("people = " + people);
```

where `List.of(1,2,3` is the id-list, `Merging::ageProvider` and `Merging::nameProvider` could take time to retrieve partial information (age, name, ...) of the `Person` pojo.

You need also a "special" supplier for the these provider

```
public interface PersonProvider extends Supplier<Person> {
    static PersonProvider of(Integer id, Function<Integer, Person> supplier) {
        return () -> supplier.apply(id);
    }
}
```

And finally you need a function that merge all together

```
private static List<Person> mergePerson(Map<Integer, List<Person>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .map(Merging::mergePerson)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Person mergePerson(List<Person> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .reduce(new Person(), Person::merge);
}
```

I hope this solve you issue :)